# How to verify in java JFrame if is form empty

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I am doing my homework in GUI.My task is to created text game in 2D. 
I would like to start that user will create his "account" in my game. 
But there is a problem, if a user pushes the button even is empty, program gives user access. 
I've used `WindowsBuiled` so only what I've did was creating `ActionListener`. 
Class Hrac(Player) is simple with 3 variables (name,surname and nickname in game). 
I've tried many options like hrac == null or for example:

```
String name,surname,nickname;
           
name = textField.getText();
                .... //(With other variables I did the same)
                ....
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if (textField != null || textField_1 != null || textField_2 != null) {
        Hrac hrac = new Hrac(textField.getText(), textField_1.getText(), textField_2.getText());
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Everything is okay");
    } else {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You have to fill everything");
    }
}
```

I've already tried Exception inside class(if(name.length < 3)) class in setName,setSurname ... ,but without succes.

Answer (score 0):

`textfield != null` checks whether your textfield exists. I suppose that you create it somewhere else. Thus, `textField != null || textField_1 != null || textField_2 != null` will never be false.

You should check instead if the textfields are empty. This can be done with `textField.getText().trim().isEmpty()`.

---

`getText()` gives you the content of the text field

`trim()` removes leading and trailing whitespaces

`isEmpty()` returns true if the string is empty

Comment: Yeah,you right!Thank you mate!I did the same in case,if user's input will be just single word.Have nice day!

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            
                  if(textField.getText().trim().length() >  3 ||  textField_1.getText().trim().length() > 3 && textField_2.getText().trim().length() != 0 ) {           
                      Hrac hrac = new Hrac(textField.getText(), textField_1.getText(), textField_2.getText(),0,0,0,0);  
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Vše je v pořádku \n" + "Vítej" + " " + textField_2.getText());
                        btnNewButton.setEnabled(false);
                        
                } else {               
                     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Jméno a příjmení musí obsahovat minimálně 3 znaky!");
                }
              
            }
        
    });
```

Comment: user has to enter atleast name and surname 2 lenght